# How to show RSS icon for a views feed?

Tags: 7, feeds

I created a feed for one of my views. I was under the impression that Drupal would automatically display an RSS icon on a view that has a feed?
I see that page.tpl.php prints an icon:

However, I'm not seeing the icon. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to attach your `Feed` display to one of your `Page` displays (within the same view).

To do this, in `Feed settings` click on `Attach to: None` and tick one of previously created `Page` displays (or create one first if you haven't already done so). Only then the RSS icon will be displayed on the page your feed is attached to.

Here's a screen shot for anyone who (like me) can't see the wood for the trees.
[image: For other people with Views Blindness]

Comment: Thanks Maciej, I've added a screengrab as I was looking in the wrong place for a while.